# How to simulate from sum of two exponential distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, simulation

I have a mixed exponential distribution:
$$
F(x) = 1 - p\exp^{-\alpha x} - (1-p) \exp^{-\beta x}\:\:\text{ for }\ x \geq 0
$$
I saw a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321370/simulation-of-asymmetric-double-exponential-distribution) but the domain for $x$ is quite different there. So how to simulate the distribution here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to simulate an exponential random variable, all you have to do is toss a coin which comes heads with probability $p$.

If the coin comes heads, generate an exponential random variable with parameter $\alpha$. Otherwise, generate one with parameter $\beta$.

A coin toss is a simple discrete distribution on $\{0, 1\}$ with probability $p$ of outcome $0$.

Hope this helps. If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: I just dont understand why we are ignoring the beta part of the distribution when the coin comes head. The other post is straightforward because when x is less than 0 or x is greather than 0, it acts like an exponential.

Comment: Perhaps a formal proof that the above actually generates the mixture you desire will convince you. Give me some time and I'll update my answer.